# Kubernetes ClusterIP versus headless service scenario

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service

I understand the concepts of a Kubernetes service ClusterIP and Headless service but when would I use one over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common case is to use `ClusterIP` for services within your cluster, unless you have a specific reason for another kind of `Service`.

> For headless Services, a cluster IP is not allocated, kube-proxy does not handle these Services, and there is no load balancing or proxying done by the platform for them. How DNS is automatically configured depends on whether the Service has selectors defined

A specific reason for a *headless* service may be when you use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/).